# How is exec.Command breaking this call to sed?

Tags: go, sed

I'm trying to run the following command from go.

sed -i 's|/home/output||g' /tmp/results.json

Which blats out /home/output from the file /tmp/result.json.

If I run this from a terminal it works perfectly.  However, I can't figure out why it's not liking being run from go exec.

Here is my code.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "os"
        "os/exec"
)

func main() {
        cmd := exec.Command("sed", "-i", "'s|/octane/data||g'", "./results.json")
        cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
        cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

        if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
}
```

The specific error is:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
2018/03/07 11:48:01 exit status 1
```

What is causing this unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
cmd := exec.Command("sed", "-i", "s|/octane/data||g", "./results.json")
```

wrong quoting issue.

The single quotes are necessary for shell but not for the exec.Command call.

Comment: In particular, Go calls the command directly, not through a shell, so it is not necessary to escape or quote characters that a shell might treat specially.

Comment: Thanks that's what I discovered by trial and error.  It actually pulls the command from a toml file which had the single quotes.

Comment: Oh, I hope you get those TOML files from a trusted source…

Comment: It's a configuration file.  Not user editable.  Written by me.

Comment: What if the regex pattern contains whitespaces in it, how should we use exec.Command to execute sed command at all?